# Indexing a function call

Tags: r, function, call

I am doing a deception game and i am trying to simulate with R.
I have a random vector A of length n. I want a function . for eg- extract such that the 1st time the user uses extract() ,he gets A[1], the second time he gets A[2] till A[n]. I know it will be much easier if i can have a argument for i inside the extract function but i do not want to give the impression that we are recording the users actions.

My try

```
j<-1

extract<-function(){
  B<-numeric(n)
  x<-sample(c(1:6),1)
  B[i]<-j
  j<-j+1
  return(x)
}
```

and then call B to get the vector of results
But its not working

Comment: You need to create a "side effect". Save the index somewhere (e.g., in the `.GlobalEnv` or another environment) and have your function retrieve and update that index each time `extract` is called. You can use `assign()` for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Took me a day to figure it out. Works finally

Comment: By the way, how do i update the index anytime an concerned function is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an environment to record the indexing variable `i` and your vector of values `A`. Then, each time you call `extract` you can pull the current index `i`, update that index in the environment, and return the appropriate value of `A`. This procedure is known as a "side effect" because calling `extract()` performs actions that modify values in the workspace other than the return value of the function. It's also a somewhat uncommon approach in R because the function performs actions on objects in the workspace that are not explicitly passed to `extract`.

```
e <- new.env()
e$i <- 1
e$A <- 1:15

extract <- function() {
    x <- e$A[e$i]
    e$i <<- e$i + 1
    return(x)
}

extract()
# [1] 1
extract()
# [1] 2
extract()
# [1] 3
extract()
# [1] 4
extract()
# [1] 5
```

You will probably want to introduce an `if` statement to change the behavior of `extract` once you've reached the end of the `A` vector.

Comment: thanks a lot. Relieves me from the burden of learning python :)